# Modal Bootstrap locked at the second call

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Modal Bootstrap locked at the second call

I have been testing the demonstration in the [Live Demo](https://www.phpflow.com/demo/simple-modal-box-dynamic-content-demo/) and when I press the "Show Modal" button twice it locks and I can not press it again

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic content Using remote URL</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container ">
<div class="jumbotron"><a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="modellink">Show Modal</a></div>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

modalbox.php Code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sample Model Box - Header Area</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = "modalbox.php";
        jQuery('#modellink').click(function(e) {
            $('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
                $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

test this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp, it use the button as toggle, are you have a button code like this :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. It appears to be working fine. You can keep pressing the button several times, the modal will keep appearing. Try it at the following [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/37nYPqKcs8zZAimdNy26?p=preview).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic content Using remote URL</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var url = "modalbox.php";
      jQuery('#modellink').click(function(e) {
        $('.modal-container').load(url, function(result) {
          $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true
          });
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="jumbotron"><a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="modellink">Show Modal</a></div>
    <div class="modal-container">
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Sample Model Box - Header Area</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I fix the problem adding the $('#myModal').modal('dismiss'); after jQuery('#modallink').click(function (e) {

Comment: Please give me your comment about this solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = "modalbox.php";
        jQuery('#modellink').click(function(e) {
            $('#myModal').modal('dismiss');
            $('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
                $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```